# Entity Framework imports stored procedure despite that option is not selected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-database-first

I've got a database which has lots of tables, views and stored procedures. When I try to Update model from database it takes also a stored procedure, although I didn't asked for it.
[image: Update Wizard]
When I compile the code it gives me errors, so I have to manually remove stored procedure from Context file:
[image: Compilation Errors]

Added part to usings section:
[image: usings section]

Added part to the context file:
[image: context body]

How to prevent getting that stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by opening .edmx file in XML editor and removing all nodes containing `sp_rt_Pivot` function. Worked well, but seems it's a EF bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the stored procedure from the model browser for your model. The stored procedure will appear in `Function Imports`. Now after this, try Ctrl+A in your model and delete all entities and then update your model from the database selecting only tables and see how it goes.

As far as the namespace error is concerned, try replacing `System.Data.Objects` with `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried that but with no results. Function was still populated. Removing it manually from .edmx worked but you deserve an upvote for trying help.